# How to disable specific column Sorting in Datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, .net-1.1

In winforms .Net Framework 1.1, is there any way to disable sorting on specific column in datagrid.

If I try to set Allow sorting equal to false, then it disable sorting in all columns. But I need to disable specific columns in the datagrid.

```
this.dataGrid1.AllowSorting = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control doesn't have a property to control sorting of columns separately. You can just allow or disallow sorting of all columns by setting `AllowSorting`.

But looking into [source code of the control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGrid.cs,e9fdd3ed845b09e6), the control performs sorting by handling mouse up, by hit-testing to check if the mouse up if happening on column header. So to customize the behavior, you can override `OnMouseUp` and fool the base method by passing a fake mouse event args:

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hti = HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        var newArgs = new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, -1, -1, e.Delta);
        if (hti.Type == HitTestType.ColumnHeader && hti.Column == 0)
            base.OnMouseUp(newArgs);
        else
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `MyDataGrid` control on form:

[image]

You can enhance the code example and add a property to contain a list of sortable or non-sortable properties and instead of `hti.Column == 0` check for those sortable/non-sortable column indices.

Comment: Changed the solution to not use `AllowSorting`.

Comment: how can i get current click area column index in datagrid?

Comment: [DataGrid.HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.hittest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by column number as follows,

```
// Make fourth column not sortable
dataGridView1.Columns[3].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Comment: In .net  1.1 . there is no DatagridView Control. i need to disable specific column sorting in Datagrid.